# Tizen wearable: Can you get sensors data in ambient mode?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

Sorry. I'm new to tizen. Can't find answer at official tizen forum.
Wan't to develop specific watchface for tizen watches.
Can you get sensors data in ambient mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can Get/fetch the Sensor Data while in ambient mode. The Issue is in Showing sensor data in ambient mode.

**If you are Using GearWatchDesigner:**

You are only able to use the features that are being offered by the designer tool.

# You may add 'Text' Component like 'step %','heart rate', on your watchface. It would be shown on both Ambient mode & Active mode.

# You may add 'Complication' Component like 'heart rate','steps' on your watchface. But you can't show the 'Complication' component in ambient/always-on mode. It's only available in Active mode.

**If you are Using Tizen-Studio IDE :**

You are free to develop your watchface in ambient mode using Tizen API.
Use [Tizen sensor API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/sensors) to get Sensor data, and add UI components to present them. But then, It's your responsibility to meet the 'less than 15% of the pixels' limit. [Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/application-management/applications/ui-application/efl-applications/watch-application)

Check out [Samsung developers:Gear](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/) for details